# Slack bot install to include custom emojis?

Tags: node.js, emoji, slack-api, slack

I'm building a slack bot and wonder if there is a way to add emojis to a team when the bot is installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't possible. There's no API to do that.